# parsing json list of entry and display in html populating vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

i am getting List< Entry< String, Integer>> as json response from below code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/responseString", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    public String responseString(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        try{
List<Entry<String, Integer>> result =  Util.topNKeys(Util.getvalues(resultSet, 2), 3);
            return JSONSerializer.toJSON(result).toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
}}
```

by calling ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<%=request.
getContextPath()%>/responseString',
                    data: ({batchId: batchId, clientId:clientId}),
success: function(data) {   
                var listEntryData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                alert("Error occured. Please try after some time.");
            }
        });
```

i get below reponse

```
[it help me=1, is a good=1, how to spend=2, like myself it=3, my mo ey=4, people like myself=5, me to understa=6, understa d how=7]
```

i want to display it like below

```
   it help me: 1   how to spend: 2    my mo ey=4             me to understa: 6
   is a good: 1    like myself it: 3  people like myself: 5  understa d how: 7
```

**Display of contents has to :**

**1.)Population has to be vertically from top to bottom, with left alignment**

**2.)It must have 4 columns and rows depending on contents, i.e if data count is 
   14. it should have 4 rows.**

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to try getJSON method for retrieving json data.
just do it as this...

```
$.getJSON("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/responseString",{batchId: batclientId:clientId},function(data){
      if (data){
         $.each(data , function(){
            $("#block").append('<div class="col-md-3">'+this['key1']+' : '+this['key2']+'</div>');
            });
      }
      else{
         alert("Error occured. Please try after some time.");
      }
   });
```

and place the div with id #block and class .row where you want to show these data.

```
<div id="block" class="row"></div>
```

I am not sure about the JSP code hope this works for you...